# CssRewrite filter does not convert relative urls to absolute

Tags: php, css, asset-pipeline, assets, assetic

I'm trying to combine all used css files into a single one. But included resources with relative paths causes problems. I tried assetic's CssRewriteFilter but it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
    $files = [
        '/node_modules/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css',
        '/node_modules/jquery-datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.css',
        '/node_modules/icheck/skins/square/blue.css',
        '/node_modules/Plupload/js/jquery.plupload.queue/css/jquery.plupload.queue.css',
        '/node_modules/pace/themes/white/pace-theme-flash.css',
        '/node_modules/lightgallery/dist/css/lightgallery.min.css',
        '/node_modules/x-editable/dist/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css',
        '/node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.css',
        '/node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css',
        '/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css',
        '/node_modules/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.min.css',
        '/theme/assets/skin/default_skin/css/theme.css',
    ];

    $am = new \Assetic\AssetManager();

    $items = [];

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $filename = APP_ROOT_DIR . '/public/ui' . $file;
        $items[] = new \Assetic\Asset\FileAsset($filename, [new \Assetic\Filter\CssRewriteFilter()]);
    }

    $collection = new \Assetic\Asset\AssetCollection(
        $items
    );
    $collection->setTargetPath('vendor.css');

    $am->set('collection', $collection);

    $writer = new \Assetic\AssetWriter(APP_ROOT_DIR . '/public/ui/shared/css/');
    $writer->writeManagerAssets($am);
```

What i expect:

When a img is included with `../img/test.png` code in `/node_modules/test/css/test.css` Assetic should rewrite it to `/node_modules/test/img/test.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try constructing your `FileAsset` class like:

```
new \Assetic\Asset\FileAsset(
    $filename,
    [new \Assetic\Filter\CssRewriteFilter()],
    '/node_modules/test/'
);
```

In `src/Assetic/Asset/FileAsset.php:37`, we see that you can include a `$sourcePath` as a third argument.

https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/blob/master/src/Assetic/Asset/FileAsset.php#L37

You may want to rejig your `$files` array to something like

```
$files = [
    ['/node_modules/select2/dist/css/', 'select2.min.css']
    ...
];
```

So that you can call the `$sourcePath` twice over like

```
new \Assetic\Asset\FileAsset(
    APP_ROOT_DIR . '/public/ui' . $file[0].$file[1],
    [new \Assetic\Filter\CssRewriteFilter()],
    '/public/ui'.$filename[0]
);
```

Comment: Aren't you confusing $sourceRoot (3rd argument) with $sourcePath (4th argument). Check the code in your link again. You are actually duplicating functionality.